# Python TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object, 18 line

Tags: python

```
users = [
    { "id": 0, "name": "Hero" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "Dunn" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Sue" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Chi" },
    { "id": 4, "name": "Thor" },
    { "id": 5, "name": "Clive" },
    { "id": 6, "name": "Hicks" },
    { "id": 7, "name": "Devin" },
    { "id": 8, "name": "Kate" },
    { "id": 9, "name": "Klein" }
]

friendships = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8), (8, 9)]

friendships = {user["id"]: [] for user in users}

for i, j in friendships:         #Ошибка здесь
    friendships[i].append(j)
    friendships[j].append(i)

print(friendships)

""" Нужно вывести словарь со списком друзей у каждого пользователя(id)"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
users = [
    { "id": 0, "name": "Hero" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "Dunn" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Sue" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Chi" },
    { "id": 4, "name": "Thor" },
    { "id": 5, "name": "Clive" },
    { "id": 6, "name": "Hicks" },
    { "id": 7, "name": "Devin" },
    { "id": 8, "name": "Kate" },
    { "id": 9, "name": "Klein" }
]

friendships0= [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8), (8, 9)]

friendships1 = {user["id"]: [] for user in users}

for i, j in friendships0:
    friendships1[i].append(j)
    friendships1[j].append(i)
    

print(friendships1)
```

Comment: а какой результат `print(friendships)` ?

Comment: Ну сейчас он выводит {0: [0, 0], 1: [1, 1], 2: [2, 2], 3: [3, 3], 4: [4, 4], 5: [5, 5], 6: [6, 6], 7: [7, 7], 8: [8, 8], 9: [9, 9]} а по идее должен выводить в списке каждого пользователя его друзей у 0 например 0: [1, 2]